# Login returns extended model not the base model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Disclaimer: I'm one month into Python and Django, and building my first project as a budding programmer.

**Desired functionality:**  A new user opens up the app and registers a username and password.  They are then taken to a profile page where they input a series of things. They submit it, and they should now be linked to a user (creator) and a profile (content).  They can only see and edit their page.

**Current problem:**  When I log in as the admin, I can see all profile information.  When I log in as a regular user, I only see the information requested at registration (username) for that user. I do not see any profile information, although the fields(empty) are there.  Effectively, the login is taking me to the user but NOT the profile.  I'm guessing I have problems in my models.  Should I start over with an AbstractUser model and then use a One-To-One with the extended Profile model?  I think I may have done this backwards.  Thank you!!

**What I See When:**

Logged in as User "bbasil":

Student Name:

Preferred First Name: 
Email: bbasil@gobble.edu
 
School Name: 
Short Bio: 
Interests: , ,

Logged in as "Admin":

Student Name: Blanche Camille Basil

Preferred First Name: Betty
Email: bbasil@gobble.edu
School Name: Gobble University
Short Bio: I like to make ice sculptures, bake baguettes, and salsa dance.
Interests: Sculpture, Baking Bread, Salsa Dancing

MODELS.PY

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.template import Template, Context
from utils import get_domain
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Timestamp(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 'Alphanumeric characters only.')

class Profile(Timestamp):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, validators=[alphanumeric])
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, validators=[alphanumeric])
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, validators=[alphanumeric])
    preferred_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, validators=[alphanumeric])
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    short_bio = models.TextField()
    interest1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    interest2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    interest3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    webcode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)

    def middle_initial(self): # doesn't seem to work for domain logic
        t = Template('{{ first_name|slice:"1" }}')
        c = Context ({'first_name': first_name })
        return t.render(c)

    @property # what does this do?
    def name(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.webcode: # What are these ifs saying?
            self.webcode = User.objects.make_random_password(length=10)
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        if not self.domain:
            self.domain = get_domain(first_name=self.first_name, middle_name=self.middle_name, last_name=self.last_name, preferred_name=self.preferred_name)
        return super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['profile_images', instance.profile.slug, filename])


class User(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, blank=True, null=True, related_name="creators")


class Upload(Timestamp):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="uploads")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from student_profile.forms import ProfileForm, UploadForm
from student_profile.models import Profile, Upload


def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
    else:
        if request.user.is_superuser:    
            profiles = Profile.objects.all().order_by('last_name')
            return render(request, 'index.html', {
                'profiles': profiles,
                })
        else:
            profile = request.user
            return render(request, 'profiles/profile_detail.html', {
                'profile': profile,
            })

def profile_detail(request, slug):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)
    uploads = profile.uploads.all()

    return render(request, 'profiles/profile_detail.html', {
        'profile': profile,
        'uploads': uploads,
    })

def edit_profile(request, slug):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form_class = ProfileForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile_detail', slug=profile.slug)
    else:
        form = form_class(instance=profile)    
    return render(request, 'profiles/edit_profile.html', {
        'profile': profile,
        'form': form,
    })

def create_profile(request):
    form_class = ProfileForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.slug = slugify(profile.name)
            profile.save()
            return redirect('profile_detail', slug=profile.slug)
    else:
        form = form_class()    
    return render(request, 'profiles/create_profile.html', {
        'form': form, 
    })

def edit_profile_uploads(request, slug):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form_class = UploadForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forn_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            Upload.objects.create(
                image=form.cleand_data['image'],
                profile=profile,
            )

            return redirect('edit_profile_uploads', slug=profile.slug)

    else:
        form = form_class(instance=profile)
        uploads = profile.uploads.all()    
    return render(request, 'profiles/edit_profile_uploads.html', {
        'profile': profile,
        'form': form,
        'uploads': uploads,
    })
```

**REGISTRATION AND SIGNUP PAGES** 
Both are cookie cutter from Django:

**registration_form**

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Registration Form - {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Register an Account</h1>

<form role="form" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**create_profile**

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Create a Profile - {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Create Your Profile</h1>

<form role="form" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Django's User class has some of the fields that you are using in profile... Try to take advantage of that. The problem could be in your views.py file. Can you show your view code?

Comment: Can you include the code related to the registration and signup page?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I should not have logged into the admin and front end with the same browser.  I fixed this by logging into the admin using Incognito Mode so that the admin login doesn't override the current user's session.

I felt a little silly when I discovered this, but might help another person new to Django!